# MYSQL Workbench connection attempt failed

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MYSQL Workbench.
When I tried to open my local instance of mysql, this error message pops up.

> > Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost3306:
> >
> > > Can't create TCP/IP socket(10107)

It was fine yesterday. And I did not change any setting before.

I suspected that the mysql service has stopped. However, when I checked, it is started. But i restarted it anyway. Nothing changes. Restarted the pc too, nothing's changed.

FYI, I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bits.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Sorry for the poor english.

Comment: Can you ping using `mysqladmin`?

Comment: It said that 'mysqld is alive'

Comment: I solved it !!!!!!!
Apparently 10107 is a windows socket error code.
The Windows sockets configuration seems to be corrupted. What I did was open up command prompt as administrator, execute 'netsh winsock reset' and reboot my pc.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your sql server is not running. If you have not installed the sql server get it downloaded and installed using the sql installer.

If you have already installed the sqlserver and facing this issue goto start search for services, in services check whether sqlserver is running if not enable it.